# d3.js scaling and translating a force layout to the center of a viewport

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3.js force layout with some tweaks to the force calculations.  As I'm working with large datasets, sometimes the graph is partly or entirely outside of the viewport.  I'd like to add a command to rescale and center the graph to be inside the viewport, but having some trouble with that.

#### what works:

I have a canvas and a viewport onto it:

```
this.svg_canvas = d3.select("#" + this.container_id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width)
    .attr("height", this.height)
    .call(this.zoom_behavior.bind(this))
;

this.viewport = this.svg_canvas.append("g")
    .attr("id", "viewport")
;
```

I have a zoom behavior that scales and translates the viewport:

```
this.zoom_behavior = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([GraphView.MIN_ZOOM, GraphView.MAX_ZOOM])
    .on('zoom', this._handleZoom.bind(this))
;

GraphView.prototype._handleZoom = function() {
    var translate = d3.event.translate;
    var scale = d3.event.scale;
    this.viewport.attr("transform",
                       "translate(" + translate + ") " +
                       "scale(" + scale + ")");
};
```

All of that works as it should.

#### what doesn't work

I added a "recenter and scale" method that is supposed to perform the scaling and translation to bring the graph onto the viewport.  The way it is supposed to work is that it first finds the extent of the graph (via my `boundingBox()` method), then call `zoom.behavior` with the appropriate scaling and translation arguments:

```
GraphView.prototype.recenterAndScale = function(nodes) {
    var bounding_box = this._boundingBox(nodes || this.force.nodes());

    var viewport = this.zoom_behavior.size();      // viewport [width, height]
    var tx = viewport[0]/2 - bounding_box.x0;
    var ty = viewport[1]/2 - bounding_box.y0;
    var scale = Math.min(viewport[0]/bounding_box.dx, viewport[1]/bounding_box.dy);
    this.zoom_behavior.translate([tx, ty])
        .scale(scale)
        .event(this.svg_canvas)
    ;
};
```

This doesn't work.  It (usually) locates the graph the edge of my viewport.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong reference for something.  Is there an online example of how to do this "properly" (using the d3 idioms)?

For completeness, here's my definition of `boundingBox()` -- it returns the geometric center and extent of the nodes in the graph.  As far as I can tell, this is working properly:

```
// Return {dx:, dy:, x0:, y0:} for the given nodes.  If no nodes
// are given, return {dx: 0, dy: 0, x0: 0, y0: 0}
GraphView.prototype._boundingBox = function(nodes) {
    if (nodes.length === 0) {
        return {dx: 0, dy: 0, x0: 0, y0: 0};
    } else {
        var min_x = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var min_y = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var max_x = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var max_y = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
            if (node.x < min_x) min_x = node.x;
            if (node.x > max_x) max_x = node.x;
            if (node.y < min_y) min_y = node.y;
            if (node.y > max_y) max_y = node.y;
        });
        return {dx: max_x - min_x,
                dy: max_y - min_y,
                x0: (max_x + min_x) / 2.0,
                y0: (max_y + min_y) / 2.0
               };
    }                                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually pretty easy: I needed to apply the effects of scaling when computing the translation.  The corrected `recenterAndScale()` method is:

```
GraphView.prototype.recenterAndScale = function(nodes) {
    var bbox = this._boundingBox(nodes || this.force.nodes());
    var viewport = this.zoom_behavior.size();  // => [width, height]
    var scale = Math.min(viewport[0]/bbox.dx, viewport[1]/bbox.dy);
    var tx = viewport[0]/2 - bbox.x0 * scale;  // <<< account for scale
    var ty = viewport[1]/2 - bbox.y0 * scale;  // <<< account for scale
    this.zoom_behavior.translate([tx, ty])
        .scale(scale)
        .event(this.svg_canvas)
    ;
};
```